# Why does deriving from a class cause an error about the parent constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, class, constructor

My current code looks like this

```
this.actHandler = new MainAct(reqParams[2], new DatabaseHandler());

RegisterAct regAct = new RegisterAct();

return regAct.RegisterAction();
```

**MainAct class**

```
class MainAct
{
    protected DatabaseHandler dbh;

    protected MySqlConnection db;

    protected MySqlDataReader reader;

    protected MySqlCommand cmd;

    protected string param;

    public MainAct(string param, DatabaseHandler dbHandler)
    {
        this.param = param;
        this.dbh = dbHandler;
        this.db = this.dbh.ConnectDatabase();
    }
}
```

**RegisterAct class**

```
class RegisterAct : MainAct
{
    public string RegisterAction()
    {

    }
}
```

And Im getting the following error :

> BloodServer.act.MainAct doesnt contain a constructor with 0 args

This is in the Parent class, which I thought I replaced.
Does the Parent constructor still get called?  Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Yes. See http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your RegisterAct class, you need to add a constructor which calls the base constructor with the right parameters:

```
class RegisterAct : MainAct
{
    public RegisterAct(string param, DatabaseHandler dbHandler) : base(param, dbHandler)
    {
    }

    // Other methods/code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to know how to construct the base class part of your derived class. By default, it will call the parameterless constructor on the base class. Since you don't have one, it tells you it can't call it since it doesn't exist.

That's why you need to either implement a parameterless constructor on the base class, or preferably, call the overloaded constructor.

Either like this:

```
public RegisterAct() : base("value for param", new DatabaseHandler())
{ }
```

Or this:

```
public RegisterAct(string param, DatabaseHandler dbHandler) : base(string param, DatabaseHandler dbHandler)
{ }
```

Comment: @Alvaro: need more help?